# What is this alert called?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, popup, alert

Building a front-end in react, I have a number input within a form that makes this alert popup when I have invalid input. What is this called? Trying to use it in different areas as an alert but not sure if it's possible to make a custom one.

Tried googling modals but no work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing are you looking is Formik and Yup Validation
Please check this:
https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation

For notifications for submissions both below are a bit helpful.

For Material UI please check:
https://mui.com/components/snackbars/

For Chakra UI please check:
https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/feedback/toast

But preferably I find chakra UI toast a a little bit of handful when it comes to
axios request, you can create a custom hook for the toast and use it as a callback
and insert a message and status in it.